# Portal is empty in Filemaker?

Tags: filemaker

I created a portal and added it to my form and added the fields I wanted to the "Add Fields to Portal" box. [What I have in edit mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhYsv.jpg)

However, after going into browse mode, the portal is empty. [What I have in browse mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MNYt.png)

[Image of what I want to have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSFIr.png)

Comment: Let me suggest again you post these questions in a forum, not here. For one thing, this is not about programming. For another, SO is a Q&A site and not suitable for the kind of dialog that would be required to get to the bottom of this. On a forum, you can post your file and have someone point out your mistake on the spot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a portal to show related data you need a relationship in place between the two tables.
On the Help menu in FileMaker you will find a link to the user guide. There you can find out how to easily set up relationships and other basic things to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a relationship something like this, between Client and Order, based on the unique Client ID. (note this uses the 'anchor-buoy' method, which I prefer).
[Relationship Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98zTv.png)

Then in your Client layout, you set-up the portal using that relationship.
[Order portal on Client layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEmBq.png)

Answer (score 0):

You will typically do this by creating a relationship between the parent and child table records:

In this example, when a record is created in the child table (contacts), the ForeignKey field has a value equal to the PrimaryKey from the parent record (Companies):

[image]